# Wrapping pre-made elements using SmartGWT?

Tags: java, html, gwt, smartgwt

I can wrap HTML button, form and other already existing elements by GWT widgets and then work with them in GWT:

```
FormPanel form = FormPanel.wrap(Document.getElementById(LOGINFORM_ID));
Button submit = Button.wrap(DOM.getElementById(SUBMIT_BUTTON));
```

Is the similar functionality available in SmartGWT? Can I "convert" plain old HTML  into `IButton` or even better into `SubmitItem`?

code-wise in SmartGWT:

```
DynamicForm form = ???
IButton submit = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any direct way of doing it. Personnaly I would try For a `SubmitItem` as it is a subclass of `CanvasItem` to set the Content of the `Canvas` of this `CanvasItem` with the Html you want to act as a `SubmitItem`.